# why does grep -A n give more lines than n?

Tags: osx, grep

I am verifying UID/GID for certain users using the dscacheutil command. Using grep with -A flag gives me what I need but the  number of lines doesn't make sense. Output below:

```
Edit8:~ edit08$ dscacheutil -q user | grep -A 6 "userX"
name: userX
password: ********
uid: 2063
gid: 1021
dir: /Users/userX
shell: /bin/sh
gecos: User X

name: userA
password: ********
uid: 2013
Edit8:~ edit08$ dscacheutil -q user | grep -A 4 "userX"
name: userX
password: ********
uid: 2063
gid: 1021
dir: /Users/userX
shell: /bin/sh
gecos: User X

name: userA
Edit8:~ edit08$ dscacheutil -q user | grep -A 2 "userX"
name: userX
password: ********
uid: 2063
--
dir: /Users/userX
shell: /bin/sh
gecos: User X
Edit8:~ edit08$ dscacheutil -q user | grep -6 "userX"
uid: 2012
gid: 1010
dir: /Users/userB
shell: /bin/sh
gecos: User B

name: userX
password: ********
uid: 2063
gid: 1021
dir: /Users/userX
shell: /bin/sh
gecos: User X

name: userA
password: ********
uid: 2013
Edit8:~ edit08$ dscacheutil -q user | grep -A 2 "userX"
name: userX
password: ********
uid: 2063
--
dir: /Users/userX
shell: /bin/sh
gecos: User X
Edit8:~ edit08$ dscacheutil -q user | grep -A 3 "userX"
name: userX
password: ********
uid: 2063
gid: 1021
dir: /Users/userX
shell: /bin/sh
gecos: User X

Edit8:~ edit08$
```

While my logic dictates the magic number of lines would be 6, in fact it is 3.

Anybody?

Thanks

Comment: Is it only outputting 3 because that's all there is in the input?

Answer (score 1):

I've marked with `~~~` the lines that match the pattern, and numbered the lines thereafter:

```
    Edit8:~ edit08$ dscacheutil -q user | grep -A 6 "userX"
~~~ name: userX
 1  password: ********
 2  uid: 2063
 3  gid: 1021
~~~ dir: /Users/userX
 1  shell: /bin/sh
 2  gecos: User X
 3  
 4  name: userA
 5  password: ********
 6  uid: 2013


    Edit8:~ edit08$ dscacheutil -q user | grep -A 3 "userX"
~~~ name: userX
 1  password: ********
 2  uid: 2063
 3  gid: 1021
~~~ dir: /Users/userX
 1  shell: /bin/sh
 2  gecos: User X
 3
```

As you can see, `grep -A n` never shows you a line that's more than `n` after the relevant match; it's just that you have some matches close together, which result in long stretches of included lines.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thank you. So if the string$ is found before the end of # requested lines, it starts over...? Unfortunately this is the output for dscacheutil so I just have to live with it

Comment: @user1183817: Well, you can grep for `" userX"` (with a space before the username) instead of just `"userX"`. Or, heck, you could grep for the entire line, `"^name: userX$"`. Either of these would only match the `name` line, not the `dir` line, so the `-A 6` would only give six lines after the `name` line.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

> **-A NUM, --after-context=NUM**
>                 Print  NUM  lines  of  trailing  context  after  matching lines.
>                 Places  a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)   between
>                 contiguous  groups  of  matches.  With the -o or --only-matching
>                 option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

In all the examples you give, each instance of `userX` is followed by the correct number of lines of context.  In cases where another instance of `userX` occurs within the context of another, the context extends to however many lines after the second instance.

Comment: `grep -6 "userX"` is equivalent to `grep -C 6 userX` (`-C` for "context"), and therefore to `grep -A 6 -B 6 userX` (`-A` for "after", `-B` for "before").

Comment: grep -6 displays 6 lines in both directions from string